# Novo DataFrame Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Tenho uma tabela em que uma das series tem como titulo `'Equipe'`, e o seguinte código conta quantas vezes o nome de cada equipe aparece, grava em um novo df e em um no arquivo do excel

O problema é que o arquivo `'exit_file.xlsx'`, que sai com duas colunas, fica com uma delas sem titulo, uma fica como `'Equipe'` e a outra sem nada.

Como é um arquivo gerado automaticamente toda vez que o programa roda, não posso simplesmente colocar um título à mão e quando preciso utilizar o end_file, não consigo referenciar a série que está sem título.

```
count = df_orig['Equipe'].value_counts()
df_dest = pd.DataFrame(count).to_excel('exit_file.xlsx')
end_file = pd.read_excel('exit_file.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 2):

Pelo que pude entender, você quer colocar um nome na coluna que foi sem nome para o arquivo `'exit_file.xlsx'`.

> ##### TL;DR
>
> ```
> count = df_orig['Equipe'].value_counts()\
>    .reset_index()\
>    .rename({'index':'MinhaColuna'},axis=1)
> count.to_excel('exit_file.xlsx', index=False)
> ```
>
> [Veja um exemplo online - ideone](https://ideone.com/M5IgB1)

#### Explicação

Para fazer isso podemos fazer algumas alterações, primeiramente vamos entender essa linha:

```
count = df_orig['Equipe'].value_counts()
```

O método [`pandas.Series.value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) retorna um `pandas.Series` que no seu caso será algo como:

```
<UmValorNaColunaEquipe>       <QuantidadeDeVezesQueEleApareceNoDataFrame>
<OutroValorNaColunaEquipe>    <QuantidadeDeVezesQueEleApareceNoDataFrame>
...
Name: Equipe, dtype: int64
```

Agora note o seguinte:

- `<UmValorNaColunaEquipe>` **é um index**, esse é o motivo para ele esta sem nome de coluna.
- `<QuantidadeDeVezesQueEleApareceNoDataFrame>` será um valor da coluna `Equipe` caso você transforme esse `pandas.Series` em `pandas.DataFrame`

#### Agora vamos começar a alterar

Sabendo que `df_orig['Equipe'].value_counts()` vai retornar um `pandas.Series` com index, podemos utilizar o método [`pandas.Series.reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) que nesse caso ele vai:

1. Transformar o **index** em uma coluna de nome `'index'`,
2. E seu `pandas.Series` também vai virar um `pandas.DataFrame` com 2 colunas `['index', 'Equipe']`.

```
count = df_orig['Equipe'].value_counts().reset_index()

# output de count
#          index  Equipe
# 0  NomeEquipe1       2
# 1  NomeEquipe2       2
# 2   NomeEquipe       1
# ...
```

[<sup>Veja um exemplo online - ideone</sup>](https://ideone.com/9BBMbt)

E após isso você ainda pode renomear sua coluna utilizando o [`pandas.DataFrame.rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html), ficando +/- assim:

```
count = df_orig['Equipe'].value_counts().reset_index().rename({'index':'MinhaColuna'},axis=1)

# output de count
#    MinhaColuna  Equipe
# 0  NomeEquipe1       2
# 1  NomeEquipe2       2
# 2   NomeEquipe       1
# ...
```

Então `count` agora é um `pandas.DataFrame` com 2 colunas, para finalizar agora não precisamos mais criar o novo `pandas.DataFrame` para salvar o xlsx, podemos utiliza a nossa variável `count`, então o código final ficaria +/- assim:

```
count = df_orig['Equipe'].value_counts()\
    .reset_index()\
    .rename({'index':'MinhaColuna'},axis=1)
count.to_excel('exit_file.xlsx', index=False)
```

[<sup>Veja um exemplo online - ideone</sup>](https://ideone.com/M5IgB1)